# How to make PC Gaming controller(Logitech F310) to work on Xbox One?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

I know Logitech F310 doesn't work with Xbox One(Because it's for PC). I see that there're some adapters(CronusMAX, Titan one etc.) using which we can make the controller work on Xbox. But I can't afford those adapters.
I have a microcontroller board with USB's. How do I build an adapter? Any Ideas? I do know few programming languages..If it helps...
If there's another way to make it work, do let me know.

Backstory: I had bought 2 Xbox controllers and they have lasted 1 year each. I can't waste anymore money on those as they're expensive.

Thanks

Comment: F310 is Xbox 360 compatible when the switch on the back is set to "X". I don't know if Xbox 360 controllers worth with Xbox One but it's worth trying.

Comment: Welcome! What type of microcontroller do you own. I might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks @Eric. I have Arduino UNO R3, Pi Pico, I can also spend $50 if needed.

Comment: So, apparently this is a bit tricky since you, what it boils down to, need a verification code from a verified genuine controller. Not to speak of the communication protocol which is likely different. I haven't found a source that spells it out easily I'm afraid.

Comment: @Eric, I have xbox one contoller which partially works(joystick drift). I'm planning to buy a RF module. The Ideais to take input from usb map the buttons and send from RF transmitter

Comment: Which is a good idea but the protocol used is not just any protocol. The controller also needs to identify with the console before the latter will accept input. It would probably be easier to fix the drift imho.

Comment: @Eric, what Idea did you have in mind? I can try to find few sources to implement it.

Comment: You will need a working controller, connect it through your Arduino, capture the registration key that goes over the protocol (if not secured) and use it to identify any other controller you want to use. Than it is just a matter of mapping inputs to outputs.